# execute mkpasswd inside awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `mkpasswd` inside `awk` to compare a file field with encryption (I use Ubuntu):

Execute:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 word abcdefgh
```

Output:

```
$6$abcdefgh$SByAdlFKQWuVuMNFUL.ERj1CxsscDs.v6nR2h2cyIkM.PAEUEqaMudTk3I/yfyFeaJY/da4dJto/1wXxMCaok/
```

Trying:

```
awk 'mkpasswd -m sha-512 $7 abcdefgh =="$6$abcdefgh$SByAdlFKQWuVuMNFUL.ERj1CxsscDs.v6nR2h2cyIkM.PAEUEqaMudTk3I/yfyFeaJY/da4dJto/1wXxMCaok/"' FS=: file > file1
```

File:

```
6:g:g:g:g:g:word1
7:g:g:g:g:g:word
8:g:g:g:g:g:word2
```

Expected output:

```
7:g:g:g:g:g:word
```

Comment: Please add content of `file` and your desired output to your question.

Comment: To call system `command` inside awk use: `awk '{system(command)}'` - maybe this will help you.

Comment: @rpoleski calling `system(command)` won't help as the OP needs to compare input data with the output of `command` and you can't directly capture the output of `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F':' '
{
    cmd = "mkpasswd -m sha-512 \047" $7 "\047 abcdefgh"
    sha = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) ? line : "N/A" )
    close(cmd)
}
sha == "$6$abcdefgh$SByAdlFKQWuVuMNFUL.ERj1CxsscDs.v6nR2h2cyIkM.PAEUEqaMudTk3I/yfyFeaJY/da4dJto/1wXxMCaok/"
' file > file1
```

See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for if/how to use `getline`, including reading from a pipe as in this case.